# Emacs: How to keep splitted window using ibuffer

Tags: emacs

In emacs I have splitted winows, but `ibuffer` removes my split whenever it is open. How to use `ibuffer` and keep splitted windows?

Comment: Your question suggests that `M-x ibuffer` deletes/closes a window if two windows are displayed in a given frame -- this is *not* accurate.  Said function just displays the `*Ibuffer*` buffer in the current window.  `M-x ibuffer-other-window` will display the `*ibuffer*` in the other window.  If you need more help, please clarify your question as one person has already voted to close -- not me, however.  Perhaps you have some elaborate user-configuration that is altering the behavior of `ibuffer` -- try it with **Emacs -Q** -- i.e., no user configuration and see if the behavior is any different

Comment: @lawlist you where right. I had this in my config on ibuffer after-load: `(fullframe ibuffer ibuffer-quit))`. This question can be closed know.